# Elasticsearch failed to parse exception-- bulk indexing

Tags: php, elasticsearch, bulkinsert

I am trying to bulk upload in elastic search and i am getting this error for every record i am trying to insert.
Please help me with this.

`{"took":2828,"errors":true,"items":[{"index":{"_index":"abc","_type":"abc","_id":"0","status":400,"error":{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse","caused_by":{"type":"not_x_content_exception","reason":"Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes"}}}}]}`

This is the code i am using
I am using 5.3 and elasticsearch driver 1.4
`<?php require_once "/var/www/ElasticSearch/models/ElasticSearchModels.php"; $params = array(); $ids = array(); for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){ $ids[] = $i; $params[] = array("here"=>"here","temp"=>"temp","pr"=>$i); } $elasticSearch = new ElasticSearch(); $elasticSearch->saveInElasticSearchBulk("products_staging","products_staging",$i‌​ds,$params); ?>`

Comment: Can you show a sample query you're sending?

Comment: Hey this is the code i am using for bulk insertion.
```<?php

require_once "/var/www/ElasticSearch/models/ElasticSearchModels.php";

$params = array();
$ids = array();
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
    $ids[] = $i;
    $params[] = array("here"=>"here","temp"=>"temp","pr"=>$i);
}

$elasticSearch = new ElasticSearch();
$elasticSearch->saveInElasticSearchBulk("products_staging","products_staging",$ids,$params);
?>```

Comment: It would be better to update your question, I guess. It would be more legible. But I can already see that you're not constructing the `$params` array correctly.

Comment: Also which PHP framework are you using?

Comment: I am using php 5.3 and elasticsearch php driver 1.4

Answer (score 0):

You're not constructing the `$params` array correctly, it should look like this instead:

```
$params = array(); 
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
  $params['body'][] = array(
    'index' => array(
        '_index' => 'products_staging',
        '_type' => 'products_staging',
        '_id' => $i
    )
  );
  $params['body'][] = array(
    'here' => 'here',
    'temp' => 'temp',
    'pr' => $i
  );
}

$elasticSearch = new ElasticSearch(); 
$elasticSearch->saveInElasticSearchBulk($params);
```

Comment: I am using the same array you are creating in function saveInElasticSearchBulk

Comment: Sure ...

```
public function bulkIndexing($data)
   {
       $this->elasticSearchClient = $this->elasticSearchClient ? $this->elasticSearchClient : ElasticSearchConnections::getConnection();
       try{
           $result = $this->elasticSearchClient->bulk($data);
       }catch(Exception $e){
           if(DEBUG){
               echo json_encode($e->getMessage());
           }
           error_log(json_encode($e->getMessage()));
       }
       if ($result) {
           return $result;
       } else {
           return null;
       }
   }
```

Comment: Again, this would better be added to your question so as to improve legibility.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue since i was using ElasticSearch php driver 1.4. The syntax for the bulk api is quite different.

```
$params = array(); 
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){



$params['body'][] = array(
    'index' => array(
        '_index' => 'products_staging',
        '_type' => 'products_staging',
        '_id' => $i
    )
  );
  $params['body'][] = json_encode(array(
    'here' => 'here',
    'temp' => 'temp',
    'pr' => $i
  );)
}

$elasticSearch = new ElasticSearch(); 
$elasticSearch->saveInElasticSearchBulk($params);
```